# How do I make an argument expected as a user ID?

Tags: javascript, arguments, bots, discord, discord.js

My question is about these lines for a Bot on Discord:

```
client.users.get("idhere")
  .send("message")
```

How do I turn it into a script where it takes an argument and expects it to be a user ID? (Can you please send a script?)

So I can type `[$dm (userid) (msg)]`

**NOTE: I want the bot to DM a user by his ID**

This is my current code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("the bot is ready...");
  client.user.setGame("prefix is $");
});

const prefix = "$";
client.on("message", (message) => {
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const cmdname = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  mention = message.mentions.users.first();
  if (cmdname == 'send') {
    if (mention == null) return;
    message.delete();
    args.shift();
    mention.send(args.join(' '));
    message.channel.send("done");
  }
});

client.login('token');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely learn the basics of js.

So basically you could first check if there is a mention and if there are none try to get the user by id.

**(Updated to Discord.js v12)**

```js
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("the bot is ready...");

  client.user.setActivity("prefix is $");
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const cmdName = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  const prefix = "$";

  if (cmdName == "send") {
    message.delete();

    let targetChannel;
    let mention = message.mentions.members.first();
    if (!mention) targetChannel = client.users.fetch(args[0]);
    // if there is no mention we tring to get user from id
    else targetChannel = mention;

    if (!targetChannel) {
      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .setDescription("You need to mention user or provide his id.");
      message.channel.send(embed).then((msg) => msg.delete(5000));
      return;
    }

    let text = args.slice(1).join(" "); // removing id or mention

    if (!text) {
      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .setDescription("You need to provide text to send.");
      message.channel.send(embed).then((msg) => msg.delete(5000));
      return;
    }

    targetChannel.send(text);
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("RANDOM")
      .setDescription("Successufully sended message.");
    message.channel.send(embed).then((msg) => msg.delete(5000));
  }
});

client.login("token");
```

Answer (score 0):

As `message.mentions.users.first();` returns undefined we can just make a simple and quick change to the mention variable:

```
const mention = message.mentions.users.first() || client.users.get(args[0]);
```

If no user is mentioned you it will try to use the ID of the User.